# Is Double Now Fully Equivalent to Real in QML?

Tags: qt, types, double, qml, decimal

One peculiar aspect of the JS-heavy declarative user interface language [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html) is its inclusion of seemingly redundant decimal number types.

The native types declare two [basic types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-typesystem-basictypes.html#basic-types-provided-by-the-qml-language) for decimal numbers, whose names are similar to those in many other programming languages: `real` and `double`.

The table in the current Documentation (v5.8) describes `double` as...

> Number with a decimal point, stored in double precision.

...and for `real`...

> Number with a decimal point

Now the odd bit.  The prior passage might lead one to believe that as with most language these are indeed different types based on the floating point precision (see: `float` and `double` in C/C++).

But that assumption is indicated to be incorrect.  The documentation for `real` [states](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-real.html):

> Note: In QML all reals are stored in double precision, IEEE floating
>   point format.
>
> This basic type is provided by the QML language.

Okay, a bit peculiar (why have two types then), but assuming that is wholly accurate, presumbably it would make sense to pick one (perhaps whichever was the standard in your codebase you're working on) and go with it.

But reportedly there's an unexpected issue, [as noted by Kent Hansen on QtDeclarative](https://git.merproject.org/mer-core/qtdeclarative/commit/aed15e776277410fb43ce2d2a9a8924359a58653):

> The type "real" was documented to be a single-precision float, but
>   that's incorrect. It's always been double.
>
> However, signal parameters of type "real" would be mapped to the C++
>   type "qreal", which can be either float or double depending on the
>   platform.
>
> Since JavaScript floating point numbers have double precision, QML
>   should use the same, to avoid potential loss of precision.

That makes me question whether the statement given in the Qt Documentation is wholly accurate.  Hansen's post was 4 years ago, back when `Qt`/`QML` `v5.1-2` were the latest versions.  Now we're at `v5.6-8`, so I'm wondering if what he reports is still an issue.

Can anybody answer whether this or any other inconsistencies still exist in the latest `Qt`/`QML` release versions (`v5.6-8`, as of Feb. 2017)?

Is this why two separate basic types for decimal numbers are included, in spite of the documentation seemingly indicates them to be identical?

Is there any other reason to use `double` versus `float` or vice versa in `QML`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the tradition of keeping backward compatibility.

In Qt4 it was a float. In Qt5 the old code with `real` and `double` can run, but the implementation of the QML engine doesn't need to bother with floats any more.

Comment: So the issue of `signal` being cast to a `float` in `c++` code is resolved?  Note, the author indicated that issue was in `Qt5`.  Can you add a link to the appropriate bug tracker, confirming?  If so I can mark this answer correct.

Comment: I still think that if you compile Qt with `-float` flag - then it'll be float. Looks like not an issue/bug, but a quick performance hack for some embedded platforms.

Comment: Great, I appreciate that final confirmation / clarification... most of the codebase I'm working on uses `real`, so I'm happy to hear that as that means I can move over the lingering `double` instances, without worries!  Thanks for the peace of mind!